# How to set an icon for a coin using truffle framework

Tags: json, solidity, truffle, bsc

Hello I am currently developing a cryptocurrency on the BSC (it is for fun.) I am using BSC Studio and truffle. I was wondering how I can set and icon for my coin I am assuming it is somewhere in Coin.json but I cant seem to find any option that mentions icons does anyone know where I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set an icon for an ERC20 standard token, you should verify the contract on the aimed blockchain explorer, and then make the procedure to set an icon from the blockchain explorer too.

Comment: Do you Know how one would do this on BSC testnet scan

Comment: You can have a look at this post https://cryptomarketpool.com/how-to-add-an-image-logo-to-your-crypto-token/

Comment: Ok thx it looks like this can only be done on the mainet which makes sence

Comment: Hope it is useful :)